# Print multiple sql statements in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have this statement that works and doesn't need to be changed:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select username from users where username = '$user' and user_type != 'manager'");
oci_execute($stid);

if (($user = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) == false){
    echo "ONE";
}else{
    echo "TWO";
}
```

How can I create another statement, for example assign another statement at variable, and place is in the main statement (for example in place of echo "ONE")?

I tried to create a variable:

```
$query = "select PLACE from CITY";
```

and I just echo "$query"; it display the text of query between "", but not checking in Oracle

Comment: For check in oracle, you must have to execute the query first.

Comment: You mean "execute"? if so.. I must just : oci_execute($query)?

Comment: In an if-else part, you should execute again.